# SQL using a query to assign ranks to records based on a sorted field

Tags: sql, sorting, ms-access, rank

I'm using microsoft access and I need to assign a rank to all my records, but access doesnt have the function. This ranking also has to be based on the sorted value of a certain field from that record. Any help or suggestions would be appreciated

Comment: Please provide sample data and desired results.

Answer (score 0):

You can calculate the ranking using a correlated subquery:

```
select t.*,
       (select count(*) + 1
        from t as t2
        where t2.field > t.field
       ) as ranking
from t;
```

Note:  This specifically implements the equivalent of the `rank()` functionality available in other databases.

Comment: Does that assign the same ranking to duplicates, or does it just give a random number if it encouters two records with the same value

Comment: @werfaderfderf . . . This assigns the same value to duplicates which is the definition of "rank" in SQL.